# plotly fill and border color

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I am using the R API of plotly, however, I observed some curious behavior in the color when filling an area. I am specifying only two colors (black and red), but plotly draws the shape border with the specified color but fill it with a lighter one.

Code example:

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly() %>%
    add_trace(x=c(2,3,3,2,NA, 6,7,7,6,NA),
              y=c(2,2,3,2,NA, 6,6,7,6,NA),
              fill="toself", 
              split=~c(rep('A', 5), rep('B', 5)), 
              mode="lines", 
              type="scatter", 
              xaxis="x1", 
              yaxis="y1", 
              color = I(c(rep(toRGB("black", 1), 5),
                          rep(toRGB("red", 1), 5)))
              )
```

Result:

[image: image produced by the aforementioned plotly code]

Any idea about how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems this is related to alpha channel, the border has no transparency, but the filled area has. However, change alpha in toRGB does not solve it.

Comment: You may want to check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49635602/1777111).

Comment: Thanks @MartinSchmelzer , but this onRender approach works only in the first rendering. If you zoom the chart it does not work anymore :-/

Comment: Oh you are right. Fixed it. Now it should work

Comment: It seems that there is no direct way to solve this issue using `plotly` features. However, @MartinSchmelzer provided a solution using html/css. Since it solves the issue, I marked it as duplicated. Anyway, a fix in future `plotly` versions would be appreciated.