# plotly fill color transparency in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

In R and plotly. How can I tried to use alpha to control the transparency of a grouped scatter plot. 
I followed the example in [Plotly's fillcolor defaults to half-transparency, want no-transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47301074/plotlys-fillcolor-defaults-to-half-transparency-want-no-transparency):

```
df <- data.frame(x = rep(LETTERS[1:5], 3), 
                 y = rexp(15, rate = 0.5),
                 z = c(rep("Adam", 5), rep("Arthur", 5), rep("Ford", 5)))
df <- arrange(df, desc(z))
plot_ly(df, x = ~x, y = ~y, color = ~z, type = 'scatter', stackgroup = 'one',
        groupnorm = 'percent', colors =  gg_color(Nv), alpha = 1, alpha_stroke = 1)
```

But the fill colours are transparent and `alpha` does not seem to do anything.
[image]

The solution given in [Plotly's fillcolor defaults to half-transparency, want no-transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47301074/plotlys-fillcolor-defaults-to-half-transparency-want-no-transparency) works:

```
library(htmlwidgets)
library(htmltools)
fillOpacity = function(., alpha = 0.5) {
  css = sprintf("<style> .js-fill { fill-opacity: %s !important; } </style>", alpha)
  prependContent(., HTML(css))
}
plot_ly(df, x = ~x, y = ~y, color = ~z, type = 'scatter', stackgroup = 'one',
        groupnorm = 'percent', colors =  gg_color(Nv), alpha = 1, alpha_stroke = 1) %>%
fillOpacity(alpha = 1)
```

Works:

[image]

However, in Shiny this gives the following warning and the opacity is lost

```
Warning in renderWidget(instance) :
  Ignoring prepended content; prependContent can't be used in a Shiny render call
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Note: The second figure is a snip in windows, because when clicking on the download png plotly button, the second graph still downloads the graph as transparent. The two issues are probably related.

Comment: There is an "opacity" argument in plot_ly. Did you tried to use it ?

Comment: you mean the alpha? I dont think there is an opacity argument. I tried it anyway and it didnt do anything. btw, I want to opacity of the fill of the scatter. not of a bar. maybe it's an option to add into layout?

Answer (score 2):

I looked here https://plotly.com/python/filled-area-plots/ and used `fill='tonexty'`. Now the `alpha = 1` works and controls the transparency of the fill.

```
ply = plot_ly(df, x = ~x, y = ~y, color = ~z, type = 'scatter', stackgroup = 'one',
        groupnorm = 'percent', alpha = 1, alpha_stroke = 1, mode = 'marker', opacity=1, fill='tonexty');ply
```

gives:

[image]

I still think this is an oversight in the API. when `stackgroup = 'one', groupnorm = 'percent'` the fill is automatically `fill='tonexty'`. there shouldn't be a need to add it in order to manipulate the opacity. Also, `alpha = 1` becoming active only because works `fill='tonexty'` has been added is confusing.